# Colorings of triangulations as a generalization of the four-color problem

Tags: graph-colorings, triangulations

My question can be viewed as a generalization of the four-color problem. Instead of a planar graph, consider a triangulation of a d-sphere. One wants to color vertices with N colors so that no two vertices connected by a 1-simplex have the same color. For a fixed d, is there an N which suffices for any triangulation? What are known upper bounds on such N?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When $d>2$, $N=\infty$. I got this fact from [this preprint of Lutz and Möller](http://arxiv.org/abs/1503.08251) which discusses "higher" coloring problems in manifolds.

There are at least two routes to this:

First, as mentioned as (3) after Definition 1.1, [Walkup proved](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02392331?LI=true) that $S^3$ (in fact, all closed, connected 3-manifolds) have neighborly triangulations, i.e. triangulations in which every pair of vertices is connected by an edge.  See section 7 of Walkup's paper, which gives constructions of neighborly triangulations beginning with an arbitrary triangulation.  Thus one can construct triangulations with arbitrarily large chromatic number.

For $S^d$ with $d>3$, one can take suspensions of triangulations of $S^{d-1}$.

Lutz and Möller give another proof in section 6 of their paper (see Lemma 6.2), which relies on a construction involving [cyclic polytopes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_polytope).

Answer (score 3):

Already for $d=3$ the boundary complex of the cyclic polytope with n vertices has a *complete graph* and hence requires $n$ colors.

You may ask if restricting the class of triangulations can lead to interesting extension of the FCT. Some answers in [Generalizations of the Four-Color theorem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/189097/generalizations-of-the-four-color-theorem) are relevant.

Answer (score 1):

These questions are covered in the excellent (as usual) [post by Gil Kalai](https://gilkalai.wordpress.com/2014/12/06/coloring-simple-polytopes-and-triangulations/).

Comment: As far as I can see, Kalai discusses colorings of the dual graph of a triangulation, while I would like to color the triangulation itself. These two problems seem rather different.