# Is there anything similar to the four color theorem for 3-dimensional objects?

Tags: graph-theory

From Wikipedia:

*In mathematics, the four color theorem, or the four color map theorem, states that, given any separation of a plane into contiguous regions, producing a figure called a map, no more than four colors are required to color the regions of the map so that no two adjacent regions have the same color.*

I assume that this theorem doesn't apply to 3D objects, because each "region" could be touching every other region. Is there any kind of related theorem that applies to 3D objects?

Comment: The one about a bunch of spheres in $\mathbb R^3$ that don't intersect where you form a graph by connecting two spheres if they touch?

Comment: Have you looked through this older thread on what seems to be the same general question: 

http://mathoverflow.net/questions/189097/generalizations-of-the-four-color-theorem

Comment: I vaguely remember a torus can be colored with seven colors and maybe an analogous result for the 3 dimensional space, but I read that some 25 years ago so take it with a grain of salt.

Answer (score 7):

This is an easy result, not at all comparable to the $4$-color theorem, but it perhaps has the flavor you are seeking:

> A collection of tetrahedra forming a pure simplicial complex may be "solid 4-colored" so that no two glued face-to-face receive the same color.
>   ([arXiv abstract](http://arxiv.org/abs/1012.4017).)

The planar version is that any analogous collection of triangles can be $3$-colored.

---

[image]

---

Comment: "...pure simplicial..." -- pure?